# Code signing stopped working suddenly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, code-signing

I was making a game with swift and sprite kit (my first try), I don't know if it's relevant to the problem, but suddenly I couldn't code sign I keep getting this error : (it was working perfectly like 5 mins before)

[image]

I've checked everything played with the code signing build settings, my account in the preferences but It didn't help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just clean and rebuild again it will work or delete the derived data folder

Comment: @anishparajuli I already tried cleaning and rebuilding, it keeps failing :/

Comment: clean then restart xcode

Comment: @azimov restarting xCode didn't help but after restarting the mac did, thanks

Comment: @enzo post it as an answer so it will help others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning the project and restarting the computer fixed the problem